# Choosing validation according to enum value

Tags: spring, validation, jpa, enums, spring-annotations

I am writing a class that should define the data of a credit card with relative billing infos. The number of digits changes according to the type of the credit card. So I would like to set up an enum and change the validation annotation according to the types of the enum

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

@Data @AllArgsConstructor @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=true)
@Entity
@Table(name="BillingInfo")
public class BillingInfo extends PersonalInfo {

    @NotBlank
    private String billingAddress;


    private String creditCardId;

    ***@CustomValidatorHere***
    private Integer CreditCardCCV;

    private Integer CreditCardNumber;
    private LocalDate CreditCardEXPdate;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private CreditCardType creditCardType;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Order> orders;

    public enum CreditCardType {
        Type1, Type2, Type3
    }

}
```

I was thinking to use Passey and create a service in which dinamically the ConstraintValidator changes according to CreditCardType, with a switch case

are there more immediate solutions? Wasn't able to find anything on jpa and spring docs

thank you

Comment: Why not simply declare the validation on the `BillingInfo` class, rather than the `CreditCardNumber` field? You'll then be able to access both `CreditCardCCV` and `CreditCardType` from inside the validator

Comment: That's a good point. Did you mean creating a constraint and putting the "@ValidBillingInfo" on the class declaration? Would I be able to manage the errors while rendering a template, with Angular and Bootstrap, through a @Controller and Error class??

Comment: Probably. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply declare the validation on the `BillingInfo` class, rather than the `CreditCardNumber` field? You'll then be able to access both `CreditCardCCV` and `CreditCardType` from inside the validator

> Would I be able to manage the errors while rendering a template, with Angular and Bootstrap, through a @Controller and Error class

I don't know your exact setup, but you *will* be able to put the constraint validation on the class level and still attach the error to the `CreditCardCCV` property specifically, using:

```
constraintValidatorContext.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(
        constraintValidatorContext.getDefaultConstraintMessageTemplate())
    .addPropertyNode("CreditCardCCV")
    .addConstraintViolation()
```

Note that you might also want to use `constraintViolationContext.disableDefaultConstraintViolation()` to avoid the violation from being reported twice.